# How to remove my backslash while input have underscore

Tags: php, stripslashes

Problem when I enter any input which has `underscore (_)` data will store to my db looks like this `image\_background.png`

Example

```
$image = stripslashes($_POST['image']); // example image name image_background.png
$query = 'UPDATE product SET image="'.  $db->string_escape($image, true).'" WHERE id="'. intval($id).'"';
```

The problem coming when input has `underscore` only. If without underscore all backslashes will remove by the `stripslashes`

Let me know.

Comment: By removing the $db->string_escape you made your site vulnerable to SQL injection. Not removing but fixing it need! or at least use any other escaping function, mysql_real_escape_string for example

Comment: yes.. fixed it by another way.. thank btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$db->string_escape adding it?
and why do you use stripslashes at all?

Comment: i removed the $db->string_escape and now working. thanks. weird.